# Laravel MailChimp Integration

Tags: laravel, mailchimp

I integrated MailChimp in my server with:

```
Newsletter::subscribe('rincewind@discworld.com');
```

I can subscribe users to newsletters. Then if I want to unsubscribe them I use following:

```
Newsletter::unsubscribe('the.luggage@discworld.com');
```

Can I subscribe users again if they have been unsubscribed earlier?

Comment: yeah you can , its included in the package

Comment: How? MailChimp does not give to subscribe user again

Comment: you have to set it as pending using subscribePending

Comment: I changed from subscribe to subscribePending the same problem